# Rail minitest stub_any_instance not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, minitest

I'm trying to use `minitest/stub_any_instance` but I keep getting an error stating that `Tempfile` has no method `stub_any_instance`.  A snippet of code is below - can someone tell where where I'm going wrong?  From reading the stub_any_instance source I expected it to add `stub_any_instance` to all `object` types but perhaps there's something I'm missing.  Thanks.

```
require 'test_helper'
require 'minitest/stub_any_instance'

class MyTests < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  test "failure to create temp file causes failure" do
    Tempfile.stub_any_instance :new, raise("Fake failure") do
      ...some testing here
    end
  end
```

end

Comment: Did you ["put `require 'minitest/stub_any_instance'` in your minitest_helper.rb or test file."](https://github.com/codeodor/minitest-stub_any_instance)?

Comment: its up at the top of the file

Comment: OK, it seems to be because Tempfile is a DelegateClass.  If I try this with File is works - well sort of. Problem is that as written, the raise() occurs immediately, not when the File.new() is called.

Comment: It's even worse.  Seems that the `raise()` is called when the statement is being evaluated and if I 'fix' the statement (for example putting '1' instead) then stub_any_instance complains because `new()` is not a method and can't be stubbed.

Comment: In the end I subbed initialize and added a method to set the 'nth object fails, with this error class and this message'.  I would recommend superclassing the object because what I found was that I used Tempfile once, but the underlying code used it an additional two times so I had to fail the 'third' use initially.